Showing This Set Is a $*$-subalgebra
I am missing basically a single step to proving that the following is a $*$-subalgebra in the following problem.

Let $A$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra and $\varphi: A \longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ a weight on $A$.  Then the set $M_{\varphi} = \text{span}\{a \in A_{+} \: | \: \varphi(a) < \infty\}$ is a $*$-subalgebra.

So I know the trick to this is to show that infact $M_{\varphi} = N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi}$ where $N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi} := \text{span}\{b^{*}a \: | \: a,b \in N_{\varphi}\}$ with $N_{\varphi} := \{a \in A \: | \: \varphi(a^{*}a) < \infty\}$.  In particular, $N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi}$ is a $*$-subalgebra itself, and $N_{\varphi}$ is a left ideal of $A$, which I have shown without issue.
Observe also that if $a \in A_{+}$ with $\varphi(a) < \infty$, then $a^{1/2} \in N_{\varphi}$ so that $(a^{1/2})^{*}(a^{1/2}) = a \in N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi}$. Thus $M_{\varphi} \subset N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi}$, so I just need to prove $N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi} \subset M_{\varphi}$.  Thus, let $b^{*}a \in N^{*}_{\varphi}N_{\varphi}$ for $a,b \in N_{\varphi}$.  Since $N_{\varphi}$ is a left ideal, we have $a+b \in N_{\varphi}$ and so $$M_{\varphi} \ni (a+b)^{*}(a+b) = a^{*}a + b^{*}b + a^{*}b+b^{*}a$$ where $a^{*}a,b^{*}b \in M_{\varphi}$ so we get $$b^{*}a + a^{*}b = 2\Re(b^{*}a) \in M_{\varphi}$$ so all I need is that $\Im(b^{*}a) \in M_{\varphi}$ which will prove $M_{\varphi} \ni b^{*}a = \Re(b^{*}a) + i \Im(b^{*}a)$.  However for whatever reason, showing $\Im(b^{*}a) \in M_{\varphi}$ has been challenging, despite how simple the rest of this problem was.
Could someone point out the obvious thing I am missing here to prove that $\Im(b^{*}a) \in M_{\varphi}$ (or perhaps an even more straightforward way to prove $b^{*}a \in M_{\varphi}$)?  Thank you.

Hint: $$M_{\varphi} \ni (a+ib)^{*}(a+ib) = a^{*}a + b^{*}b + ia^{*}b-ib^{*}a.$$

Can't believe I didn't think of this, thanks!
